# Increment html input number element

Tags: html, input

I have an input element

```
<input type="number" min=0.083 step=0.5>
```

I want to increment it with 0.5 when the up and down arrows are pressed in the input element and on the keyboard.

min needs to be at 0.083. But of course this can be checked in a input/changed event for the input field.

I want

0 + step = 0.5

0.5 + step = 1

1.3 + step = 1.8

2 + step = 2.5

0.5 - step = 0.083

But what I get is

0 + step = 0.083

0.083 + step = 0.583

1.3 + step = 1.583

2 + step = 2.083

0.5 - step = 0.083

With min = 0

0 + step = 0.5

0.5 + step = 1

1.3 + step = 1.5 //which is not what I want. I need it to be 1.8

https://jsfiddle.net/6eL64umx/1/

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: lol, change min value on min=0

Comment: or try to use javascript https://jsfiddle.net/6eL64umx/2/

Comment: ... I need min to be at 0.083

Comment: @Abz12 - you should have said you need the `min` to not be `0` in the first place. you **must** explain such a thing before letting people spend their time helping you...

Comment: Yea maybe I could have been more clear. Still, with the answer I got 1.3 + step(0.5) without min will be 1.5. And in my example I wrote that I wanted 1.3 + step(0.5) = 1.8. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" class="cn" min=0 step=0.5>
```

Comment: If I enter 1.3 I'll get 1.5 when I press on the arrow. I want to it be 1.8

Answer (score 0):

A little JavaScript to help with your problem.

You will need to set the `min` attribute to 0, and let JavaScript test whether it’s too far down.

Change your HTML to:

```
<input id="test" type="number" step="0.5" min=0 data-min="0.083" value="0.083">
```

and add the following JavaScript somewhere:

```
document.querySelector('input#test').onchange=function() {
    if(this.value<this.getAttribute('data-min')) this.value=this.getAttribute('data-min');
}
```

I have set your real minimum id the `data-min` attribute so you can change it in HTML.